# Change dataType from bigquery.Value to string

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I connect BigQuery with Go language as the following API documentation demonstrates,
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries?hl=en_US

After that, I need to get sql results in specific row and column, and judge if it equals a specific string. Could I change bigquery.Value to string and how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)?

Comment: Please post a minimalist example of what you are trying to do, even if it does not work. Also, the [stackoverflow question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good start to know how ask a good question.

Comment: I followed the steps as the API document I gave ,and then I tried to wrote this before`fmt.Fprintln(w,row)` in the API document:
`if row[2] == "Transfer" && row[3] == 0 {
   fmt.Fprintln(w,row[0])
   break
  }`
  
but it seems that row[2] is a bigquery value which needs to be changed to string datatype.

Answer (score 2):

See how to use `RowIterator.Next()` [here](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#RowIterator.Next).

> Next loads the next row into dst. Its return value is iterator.Done if there are no more results. Once Next returns iterator.Done, all subsequent calls will return iterator.Done.
>
> dst may implement ValueLoader, or may be a *[]Value, *map[string]Value, or struct pointer.

`Value` is of type `interface{}` so if you are sure that value you have is string `str := fmt.Sprintf("%v", row[i])` should work. It is often better to define a `struct type` that has members representing fields of query result row (with types mapped according to the table in documentation I linked above) and give the pointer to it to `RowIterator.Next()` instead of slice/map of `bigquery.Value`.

```golang
type myRow struct {
    Name string
    Num int
}

// ...
q := client.Query("select name, num from t1")
it, err := q.Read(ctx)
// handle err
for {
    // instead of: var row []bigquery.Value
    var row myRow // <-- use custom struct type here
    err := it.Next(&row)
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    // handle err != nil
    someFuncThatTakesString(row.Name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your patient answer, I tried to use "struct type" and it works.